# AT&T Assembly - Basic loop & write

Tags: beginner, io, assembly

The code loops to display "Hello, World!" ten times. I would like someone to criticize it. I know that's far from being good assembly but I only started learning it a few days ago and I would like to improve.

Would it be better to use the `%rax` registers and `syscall` instead of `int $0x80` ?

```
.section .data
  hello: .string "Hello, world!\n"
  len = . -hello

.section .bss

  .macro write str, len
    movl $WRITE, %eax
    movl $STDOUT, %ebx
    movl \str, %ecx
    movl \len, %edx
    int $0x80
  .endm

  .macro exit code
    movl $EXIT, %eax
    movl \code, %ebx
    int $0x80
  .endm

.section .text
  .globl _start

  .equ EXIT, 1
  .equ WRITE, 4
  .equ STDOUT, 1

  _start:
    mov $1, %esi
    l:
      write $hello, $len
      inc %esi
      cmp $10, %esi
      jle l

   exit $0
```

Also, if someone could explain `len = . -hello`, that's the only thing I couldn't understand and copied online.

Comment: `. - hello` - You need to understand that `hello` refers to an address.  And that `.` refers to the "current" address.  So `.` - `hello` is the distance between the current location and hello; effectively the length of hello.

Comment: Please do not add, remove, or edit code in a question after you've received an answer. The site policy is explained in [What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with the easy one:

`. - hello` - You need to understand that `hello` refers to an address. And that `.` refers to the "current" address. So `.` - `hello` is the distance between the current location and `hello`; effectively the length of hello.

Just one of those tricks you learn.  While you could manually put the length into `len`, there's always the chance that someday someone would change the contents of `hello`, and forget to change `len`.  Done this way, it's self-maintaining. Being able to compute this at 'assembly time' rather than counting bytes during run time is also a bonus.

As for the code itself, let me start with the main point: Comments.

Assembly can be tricky to code correctly, and sometimes is even harder to maintain.  Especially when you can't figure out what #@%! the guy who was writing it was trying to do.

I realize that this is just a beginner's project.  But you should acquire the habit of commenting early:

- Comments at the top of the code telling the purpose of the file.
- Comments at the top of routines (and macros) telling what they do.
- Comments at the end of individual statements describing the intent.

As an example:

```
    exit $0 ; Exit the application with return code 0
```

While to a veteran assembly programmer this comment may seem obvious, to a beginner (and everyone is a beginner at some point), it makes the intent significantly clearer.  Just a few words of text can take a screen full of numbers and symbols and provide clarity.  Maintainers of your code (as well as your future self) will thank you.

Next (in no particular order) I would look at this section of code:

> ```
> mov $1, %esi
> l:
>   write $hello, $len
>   inc %esi
>   cmp $10, %esi
>   jle l
> ```

As I'm sure you are aware, the purpose of the `cmp` instruction is to set the flags so that you can use conditional instructions like `jle`.  However, there are other instructions that adjust those same flags.  For example, `dec`:

```
mov $10, %esi
l:
  write $hello, $len
  dec %esi
  jnz l
```

Nothing magical, but it does save an instruction.

Next we've got

> *Wouldn't it be better to use the %rax registers and syscall instead of int $0x80?*

It absolutely would be better to use `syscall`.  ***IF*** you were programming for 64bit.  `int 0x80` is correct for 32bit.  And when I say 32/64bit, I'm referring to whether the *application* is 32 bit or 64bit, not the OS you are running on.

Note: The function number (and where each of the arguments go) are different between `int 0x80` and `syscall`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I edited my post to reflect changes about your answer, would you mind taking a look again? Thanks again,

Comment: @Greg01re I've undone your edit. Please post a follow-up question instead.

Comment: Alright, in a new question I guess? If so, please close this one, thanks.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150856/follow-up-att-assembly-basic-loop-write Follow up!